# How to map over 2 Array of object in React and render to Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, mern

how can i map over 2 Array of object in React and render to one Table. what are option for this issue. should i merge these two array into one ? Please check Json Data

```
let URL1 = "http://api_url/users"
let URL2 = "http://api_url/users-card"

const promise1 = axios.post(URL1, inputValue , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});
const promise2 = axios.post(URL2, inputValue , {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
  setDataSetOne(values[0]);
 setDataSetTwo(values[1]);
});
```

```
 <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
         <TableBody>

             <TableCell>DataOne</TableCell>
              <TableCell>DataOne</TableCell>
              <TableCell>DataTwo</TableCell>

       </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
```

Json Data 1st

```
[{
    "name": "adnan hassan",
    "count": 6960
}, {
    "name": "adnan",
    "count": 69666660
}]
```

2nd Json Data

```
[{
    "keyword_idea_metrics": {
        "competition": "LOW",
        "avg_monthly_searches": "6600",
        "competition_index": "22",
        "low_top_of_page_bid_micros": "53135896",
        "high_top_of_page_bid_micros": "278963954"
    },
    "keyword_annotations": {
        "concepts": []
    },
    "text": "dubai homes",
    "_text": "text"
}]
```

Edit: Json Data has been added

Comment: Please update your question to show the shape of the data in the arrays, and the end result you'd like to see for how they would be merged/displayed in your UI.

Comment: Probably something like this `users.map(user => { const card =  cards.find(card => card.userId === user.id) // Now return JSX using card or user properties })`.

Comment: @Willow Json Data Has been added Please check it

Comment: What do your two input sources have to do with one another?  And what does either one have to do with your food/nutrition output table?  You need to put more work into your question, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one object to contain two states like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  // use one object to contain two states
  const [data, setData] = useState({ dataOne: '', dataTow: '' });
  // fetch data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const dataOne = await axios.post(URL1, inputValue, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      });
      const dataTow = await axios.post(URL2, inputValue, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      });
      setData({ dataOne, dataTow });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  // display data
  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableCell>{data.dataOne}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{data.dataTow}</TableCell>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I hope it helpful.

Comment: Hi @Prayx Thank you so much for your comment. It helped me a lot. I solved this issue by both json data merge with https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith